# Checking if a row has been selected entirely

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

My datagridview is in RowHeaderSelect mode. So clicking on the RowHeader selects the whole row.

However, at any point, when i use context menu shortcuts or shortcut keys from the keyboard, i need to check if a whole row is currently selected, or just a single cell, and perform actions accordingly. How do I check this?

Comment: How are you processing the row, won't the `CurrentRow` help you in executing your logic ? Or i guess you are better off setting the `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`

Answer (score 0):

you can check with `e.CommandName` property.

**Check foolowing patch of code**>>

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        SXEngine.Classx USER = (SXEngine.Classx)Session["APPOBJ"];        

        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            USER.bRowSelect = true;         
        }
        else
        {
            USER.bRowSelect = false ;
        }
    }
```

Study this link to get more info regarding different properties of gridview>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use CommandName method of RowCommand event's argument e.
like

```
if(e.CommandName=="Select")   
{
   //code
}
```